# How to append last field of a line in a file to a variable on powershell cli?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Here is my file `hello.txt`:

> "ReceiptHandle" = "hellomyfriend==++"

I would like to append only the last field of a line to a variable:

```
$friend = hellomyfriend==++
```

Comment: what have you tried?  is the first part always "ReceiptHandle"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is all that's in your hello.txt file.  The following would assign "" to your $friend variable...

```
$myhash = (gc 'hello.txt') -replace """","" | ConvertFrom-StringData
$friend = $myhash["ReceiptHandle"]
```

ConvertFrom-StringData makes this easy because your text is already in "something = value" format.

So what's going on here? First,

> gc 'hello.txt'

is getting the contents of your file.  I encapsulate it in () so that i can use..

> -replace """",""

.. to get rid of the surrounding double-quotes. That's piped into ConvertFrom-StringData, which converts the string into a named key/value pair [hashtable].  From there, I can access the second part by interrogating the hashtable.

Alternatively, you could put this all on one line...

```
(gc 'hello.txt') -replace """","" | ConvertFrom-StringData | %{$friend = $_["ReceiptHandle"]}
```